# How do I make my Android ContentObserver for detect changed contact detail (added, updated or deleted)?

Tags: android

I can catch the event when contact is modified. But I want to catch that modified contact details like CONTACT_ID, name, etc... Please can you help me to do that. my code is follow.

```
public class TestContentObserver extends Activity {
    int contactCount = 0;
    final String[] projection = new String[] { RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, RawContacts.DELETED };
    Cursor curval;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        curval = getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
        contactCount = curval.getCount();

        curval.registerContentObserver(new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
                getChangedContactDetails();
            }
            @Override
            public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
                return true;
            }
        });

    }



    public void getChangedContactDetails(){
        // how can I catch the affected contact details
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html, section "Lookup URI"

when registering your ContentObserver you can just register an URI that points directly to the contact you are interested in. then your observer will only get notified when your interesting contact is modified.

```
Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(lookupUri, false, new ContentObserver(){});
```

Lookup key key is unique for each record

Comment: What if new contact added @Maggie

Comment: Have you tried this? I've tried a variety of configurations of this but haven't managed to get it to work. I just get every content observer called with the URI `content://com.android.contacts/contacts`.

Comment: this is a bad answer because there's something wrong with how these URIs are treated by the content resolver. You would think onChange() would be called with the lookupUri of the contact that changed, but that's not the cast. content://com.android.contacts/contacts is the URI that comes back.